# Inserting records in access table through java

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I want to insert a record in ms access table from java. and my problem is that I have to insert less numbers of fields then the total fields available. In other word say I have 10 columns in my table and I want to provide value for only 8. it is not working by simple INSERT statement. So, I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQL` allows you to specify which columns you intend supplying data:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES ('Some', 'Value', 101);
```

The columns that havent been mentioned can either take default values or could be allowed to take a `NULL` value.

Comment: I have tried this but it gives error stating that no of fields supplied is less then the required.

Comment: Are the values which are _not_ mentioned allowed to be `NULL`?

Comment: Yes the fields are set with required property as NO

Comment: I would say to check that the code matches the no. of columns in the database. Create a query in `MS Access` with the same `SQL` to check its validity.

Comment: no the no of columns are not same I have to supply 8 out of 10.

Comment: Yes I know the no of columns are not same but you can still check that the query itself is valid by running it within `MS Access`. This localizes the testing of the `SQL`...